# Symfony2 phpunit tests failed with the error invalid mapping file in orm.yml

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, doctrine, mapping, fosuserbundle

I am new in an project and we want to resume the stand of working still yet.
I found testfiles in project. These were a good point for me to have an entry and find out the things.

So let before say, this is a Symfony 2.8 project which uses fosuserbundle.
Back to my matter: when I execute phpunit in terminal so I get MappingExceptions from doctrine:

```
PHPUnit 5.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWEWWWWWWEWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW             53 / 53 (100%)

Time: 1.4 seconds, Memory: 36.50Mb

There were 2 errors:

1) ******\*****Bundle\Tests\Controller\******ControllerTest::testIndex
Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: Invalid mapping file '******.UserBundle.Entity.User.orm.yml' for class '*******\UserBundle\Entity\User'.


/var/www/*****vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:86
/var/www/********/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/FileDriver.php:117
/var/www/********/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/YamlDriver.php:56
/var/www/********/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php:102
/var/www/*******/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:116
/var/www/*******/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:332
/var/www/*******/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:216
/var/www/********/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:265
/var/www/********/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:67
/var/www/********/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:50
/var/www/*******/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:665
/var/www/*******/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Doctrine/UserManager.php:40
```

---

It seems as something going wrong with User entity and related mapping file.
But these errors appear only when I execute phpunit. I deleted the user entity and orm file and run the commands generate entities and update schema. They work without any errors.

Here is the or.yml:

```
*****\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: fos_user
    repositoryClass: ******\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
 
    fields:
        confirm:
            type: bigint
```

and here the entity class which extends from fos superclass user

```
<?php

namespace *****\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $confirm;

    /**
     * Set confirm
     *
     * @param integer $confirm
     * @return User
     */
    public function setConfirm($confirm)
    {
        $this->confirm = $confirm;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get confirm
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getConfirm()
    {
        return $this->confirm;
    }
   
}
```

I am spending now the whole day with this issue but I can not figure out what is going wrong. It seems that for doctrine is the yml file invalid but why then it happens only with unittest?

Comment: Problem found. PHPUNIT Test framework uses the newest yaml parser of symfony version 3. But when you running symfony version < version 3 you would get with unittesting  in problems because the parsing of yaml file would be depricated and would throw exception.